# Are there transit bolts on this dryer?

Tags: dryer, bolts

We just moved into our new place and our new dryer is making strange rattling noises that sounds as if a small screw or other metal part is stuck somewhere in the machine. We checked all the accessible spaces and found no loose items.

It was suggested to me that this could be caused by transit bolts that were not removed. So before calling an engineer to come and check the dryer, I wanted to ensure this was not the case. Based on internet-research I found that these bolts are normally clearly indicated, and I can't seem to find any.

I included a picture of the back of the dryer and was wondering if anyone can confirm there are no transit bolts left?

[image]

Comment: We'd need to knw the exact model and check it agains the manual to be certain. You can look that up as easily as we can.... But the best answer, since this is new, is to call the manufacturer, complain, and have them fix it under warranty.

Comment: Model is Bosch WTE84106GB and I have checked the manual: there is no mention of transfer bolts. I called the manufacturer but it will take a week before the engineer is dropping by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

[The manual](http://www.manualslib.com/download/477939/Bosch-Wte84106gb-Installation-Instructions-Instructions-For-Use-Programme-Table.html) makes no mention of having to remove transfer bolts, if the techs want to make a stink about there being bolts and you didn't remove them: no way! Not even if they do exist.

It's probably a penny. I'm unsure, but if the problem is user created this service call might cost you money even if it's under warranty. They might claim you, "put things other than laundry", in it but I'd expect better from Bosch and would hope their warranty extends past manufacturer defects.

<sub>I've never come across TBs on a non-combo unit. It shouldn't need them; there's no spring mountings, it's all bearing surfaces.</sub>

Comment: That's what I thought. Well it's definitely not a penny as we only used it once for socks and turned it off after 1 min because of the rattling noise. Let's see what the service person finds next week. Thanks.